# get deepest (basically Y) not just last object in a UIView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

For now I am achieving it by using:

```
UIView *subView = [[self.view subviews] lastObject]
```

and then:

```
CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(subView.frame);
```

But I think there must be some better way to be 100% sure that last object is actually the deepest object in view hierarchy not just the last object in array.

Comment: The y position of a view has no relationship to its position in the subview hierarchy - what are you actually trying to find out?

Comment: I want to find a subview from UIView. I want to find maxY. Basically i want to set height of parent view based on maxy value of it's deepest subview.

Comment: that's what autolayout is for :)

Comment: actually i have achieved dynamic cell height based on every thing with autolayout programmatically. Only one thing i do not use is systemLayoutSizeFittingSiz as it's returning 0 size for me. Instead CGRectGetMaxY giving me 100% result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position in the array is related to the z-ordering of the subviews, and not their x and y positions.

Assuming that the subviews themselves don't have subviews, you need to iterate through the array:

```
CGFloat maxY = 0;

for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    maxY = MAX(CGRectGetMaxY(subview.frame),maxY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for time being i will use this approach to get dynamic height of UIView subclass thus cell's content view. As it may lower UX performance  if view heirarcy is deeper. i will try on weekend more on systemLayoutSizeFittingSize.